# Improving formatting in review, still requires 6 characters?

Tags: support, review-queues, code-formatting

I was reviewing a first post by a user, and all that was needed was to format the code part as a code sample (using the '{}' button). But it still requires 6 characters to be considered an edit. How do I go about editing the question in this case?

Comment: I understand the need for character minimums in various places, but situations like this one are especially annoying. Another circumstance I encountered was where a 404 link needed only 2 characters to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

So, fix multiple things in the post. It's not that hard. Just look for typos, grammar problems, formatting, tags. Just anything - Nothing is "perfect except for 2 characters". You can try harder to improve the post.

Comment: Well, the question for review which made me write this post had only two lines. One for a description, and one for code. Your suggestion is straightforward and applicable to most cases but sometimes, I guess I will just have to hit the skip button.

Comment: Two lines? Sounds like a bad question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant write answer. The answer had only two lines.

Comment: Then it sounds flagable as NAA.

Comment: I totally disagree: if a question is fine, but a url changed, sometimes it is perfect except for two characters. Or if they just forgot to close some bit of formatting, but didn't make any other mistakes. Have you never done that anywhere? I certainly have. I asked basically this question a while back, and the response was basically "if you can't fix anything else, and it's important to fix, flag it for a mod". Which I thought was silly, but whatever.

Comment: @neminem Flag for a *mod*? Uh... No.