# How to handle suggested edits with cosmetic changes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

While reviewing suggested edits, I often come upon very basic edits where the editor simply wraps any code related keywords using the ` character. Have a look at these:

- [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6339042)
- [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6339099)

It seems to me that the editor just wants to make a quick two points. I usually reject such edits under the category: "No Improvement Whatsoever". Is this the right thing to do?

Also, considering that SO automatically recognises low-quality questions and answers, could not such edits be recognised in the same way (and rejected/not allowed automatically)?

Comment: I've found such edits can readily be recognized by looking at the description: "improved formatting" ... But yeah, in general, I treat such edits as 'too minor'. If the editor complains I'm robbing him of his well-deserved 2 points I would point out there are lots more posts that need lots more editing than trivial code ticks.

Comment: @Jongware  - Well... Not all `"formatting improvements"` are frivolous edits. For example, I practically always approve edits that simply re-indent the code.

Comment: I just edited a post the other day that someone rejected within the same category "No Improvement Whatsoever", where I had corrected poorly indented code.  If it doesn't make code easier to read to indent it, I don't know why it would be a common practice in the first place.

Comment: "no improvement whatsoever" should be used when it doesn't even makes it easier to read, and correcting/fixing the indentation (I'm not saying changing the style, that I don't care) should be approved. Now, if there are more to fix I may consider using "Reject and edit" or "improve", depending the amount of effort I have to spend on it.

Comment: I agree. Indentation should be approved. This post however talks about the  changes where a user has simply highlighted or capitalised words. In my review experience, 4 out of 10 edits are of such a type.

Comment: Yes, back-ticking some keyword if all that is done, I'd agree, but if minimal formatting includes making a code block a code block, well worth the 2 points.  And sometimes an in-line `date` code format may be instrumental when the inline formatted word is both a keyword relevant to the question, and also a "real" word.

Comment: It's ironic you don't want to approve "cosmetic changes" when [you complained yourself 8 months ago that you couldn't make a small change](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250770/1269037).

Comment: @DanDascalescu It seems you have not read the post properly. That question had code which needed to be indented. Here, it is about reviewing posts which have edits which have simply been `highlighted like this`.

Comment: The first example edit misses enough genuine problems that it should be rejected (if in a hurry; rejected and improved if you have time on your hands) — several occurrences of 'i' that should be 'I' and an unnecessary 'thanks' paragraph.  In my view, the second has enough questionable changes that it should be rejected (or maybe rejected and improved).  The backticks around 'row' in bullet point 2 are not propagated forward to bullet point 3, and it was fine before with 'section'/'sections' outside backticks too.

Answer (score 33):

I would strongly argue to **accept edits that make micro-improvements**.

For one, it is clearly not right to reject an edit as *no  improvement whatsoever* unless it makes no improvement whatsoever. A small improvement just isn't no improvement, is it? If you want to be able to reject such edits, at the very least you need a rejection criterion that fits the bill.

For another, what about posts that have one small error in, such as a typo in the title? Must such posts go eternally uncorrected, because it's not possible to make a substantial improvement?

For my money, anything that improves the site is worth having, and rejecting something just because it only makes a small improvement is just shooting ourselves in the foot.

As for what makes an edit a micro-improvement, particularly in the context of backticks: there are correct use of backticks (see, for example, my `void f(int x)` on the subject) and there are `incorrect` uses. A correct use improves a post, by however small an amount, and an incorrect use worsens it.

Comment: It does fit the bill. Blindly enclosing things in backticks doesn't improve readability and *can* harm readability, which is what the description of the rejection reason says. As for minor edits, the general advice is "wait until you get enough reputation" or leave it to someone who does.

Comment: I agree with you that any improvement should be accepted. If it makes the post better, why reject it? Just because somebody will earn 2 Internet points for proposing it? Duh! ... However, in these particular examples, there is no improvement at all. The fist one didn't need the backticks, and the second one was actually harder to read with the suggested edit...

Comment: Maybe there should be an option to approve edit, but deprive of "2 internet points"?

Comment: @Vi. - exactly. I've proposed that in [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278109/1269037).

Comment: @Vi - this option called "Reject and Improve".

Comment: @Vi No. "I think this edit is good enough to go live, but not enough to earn you any reputation" is a thin line that we have no business crossing. It's only 2 rep per edit, up to 2000 rep total. It's our job to decide whether an edit is worth having, not whether it's worth having *and* whether the editor deserves credit for it.

Answer (score 12):

[When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text/254994#254994) enumerates where enclosing something in backticks is appropriate. For example, [Fish Below the Ice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/3920237) says:

> - Micro-snippets of code (This is especially important for HTML tags or things that resemble HTML tags, since some HTML is allowed in posts
>     and the site will try to render anything between `<` and `>`)
>
>   - `init()`
>   - `if (boolean) {`
>   - `<form action="..." method="post">`
>   - `<strong>`
>   - `<level>`
>   - `&nbsp;`

There is however such a thing as too much of a good thing and it can be abused. The backticks should be used to *improve* readability and placing them all over the place can actually harm readability. An edit which consists of nothing but these minor additions are "too minor", so I would agree that they offer "No Improvement Whatsoever". The comment "improved formatting" really indicates laziness on the suggested editor's part.

If we take a look at [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) in the help center, it says:

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to
>   suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so. The original author of a
>   question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of
>   reputation level.
>
> **Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it**. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

I bolded the part which I felt was relevant. So yes, I believe you correctly rejected these edits.

To address the [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), this MSE post [Ping an editor for repeated invalid editing behavior](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273268/3920237) says that if the edits are accepted, you can ping their username, in the comments, informing them of why their edit was inappropriate. Of course, there's nothing stopping you from improving the post yourself afterwards. On, [How to deal with bad edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265636/3920237), [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265638/3920237) says pretty much the same thing:

> First, make double-sure that the edit is actually incorrect. If you're
>   *not sure* then move on - much time is wasted arguing over edits that *really don't matter*. Yes, there are a lot of edits that are just a waste of time, but if they *do no harm* then putting further work into
>   correcting them just adds to the damage.
>
> Once you're sure,
>
> 1. Fix it. Roll back, re-edit, whatever. **Always make sure you're significantly improving the post** - I really cannot stress this
>      enough.
> 2. Leave a comment for the editor. Yes, you can ping editors by typing `@<editorname> your edit was harmful due to <reason>` or some such in
>      a comment on the post that was edited. Not a lot of folks realize
>      this, and the end result is that folks get all frustrated by edits
>      instead of just educating the editors.

It seems our moderation tools are sufficient. However, if such a feature were to be implemented, i.e. by detecting the amount of characters changed, or heuristics to compare revisions, poor editors would only try to work around it. Perhaps a warning box that says something along the lines of:

> It appears your edit consists mainly of minor code formatting changes.
>   Please try to make edits that address multiple issues within the post
>   and improve the post. Refer to our guide on [how to edit
>   posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) in the help center for
>   more information.

Answer (score 2):

"Reject-and-improve" is good option for cases like that.

Reject because such change is very minor in most cases, so should not be done by editors that require other 5 people to look, validate and approve the edit. So rejecting sends such signal and remove +2 initiative to make minor changes.

"and-improve" to actually accept the change (assuming you agree with the change).

Answer (score -4):

If your problem is that someone might be after a quick two points, then let's have an option to forfeit the points. People may want to make edits, however minor, because *it's the right thing to do*. Assuming they're after points is an assumption that may be mistaken.

If someone with over 2000 points makes a small improvement, will you still reject it?

Comment: An edit made by someone with more than 2000 points wont enter the review queue.

Comment: I believe people also make these edits just to earn points. This is a drawback of gamification in general.